# QML ParticleSystem in top of PopUp

Tags: qt, qml

I want the ParticleSystem in top of all QML stuff. But some QML Items seems to be not part of the normal z ordering. Like in following example, PopUp is always drawn in top of the particleSystem.

- z property seems not to work
- particleSystem as child of PopUp is no option

thx for help and suggestions

```qml
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Particles 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true
    Component.onCompleted: app.quickLoadGame();
    Button {
        onClicked:      popUp.open();
    }
    Popup {
        id: popUp
        x: ( mainWindow.width  - width  ) / 2
        y: ( mainWindow.height - height ) / 2
        width:      mainWindow.width  * 0.8
        height:     mainWindow.height * 0.8
        modal: true
        closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutside
    }
    ParticleSystem {
        anchors.fill:   parent
        ImageParticle {
            source:                 "qrc:/png/icon/xp.png"
        }
        Attractor {
            pointX:                 mainWindow.width / 2
            pointY:                 0
            strength:               1000
            affectedParameter:      Attractor.Velocity
            proportionalToDistance: Attractor.Constant
        }
        Emitter {
            x:                      mainWindow.width / 2
            y:                      mainWindow.height
            lifeSpan:               3000
            velocity:               AngleDirection { angleVariation: 180; magnitude: 100 }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Because the App has dozens of Dialogs/PopUps, and the Particles should
>   be drawn also after PopUp was closed

Using the QML [States](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-state.html)

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: mainWindow
    visible: true

    Row {
        Button {
            text: "popUp1"
            onClicked:      popUp1.open();
        }
        Button {
            text: "popUp2"
            onClicked:      popUp2.open();
        }
    }

    Popup {
        id: popUp1
        x: ( mainWindow.width  - width  ) / 2
        y: ( mainWindow.height - height ) / 2
        width:      mainWindow.width  * 0.8
        height:     mainWindow.height * 0.8
        modal: true
        closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutside
    }
    Popup {
        id: popUp2
        x: ( mainWindow.width  - width  ) / 2
        y: ( mainWindow.height - height ) / 2
        width:      mainWindow.width  * 0.8
        height:     mainWindow.height * 0.8
        modal: true
        closePolicy: Popup.CloseOnEscape | Popup.CloseOnPressOutside
    }
    ParticleSystem {
        id: particleSystem
        states: [
            State {
                when: popUp1.visible
                ParentChange{ target: particleSystem; parent: popUp1.contentItem;}
            },
            State {
                when: popUp2.visible
                ParentChange{ target: particleSystem; parent: popUp2.contentItem;}
            }
        ]
        anchors.fill: parent
        ImageParticle {
            source:                 "flower.png"
        }
        Attractor {
            pointX:                 mainWindow.width / 2
            pointY:                 0
            strength:               1000
            affectedParameter:      Attractor.Velocity
            proportionalToDistance: Attractor.Constant
        }
        Emitter {
            x:                      mainWindow.width / 2
            y:                      mainWindow.height
            lifeSpan:               3000
            velocity:               AngleDirection { angleVariation: 180; magnitude: 100 }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: seems like a working solution. With the downside that the particleSystem must know the dialogs... so far, as a workaround it fits for my problem, so i check the answer as accepted. thx

Answer (score 0):

Just use `Item` instead  of `Popup`

Thats easy enough...

OR you could make a second particle system and then have it communicate with the first one or some kind of controller which instructs it what  particles to make and where to make them... and then just have the Popup have its own particle system that is duplicated underneath it, so it looks like you have particles above the Popup, but in reality, they will stop at the edge of the Popup and continue on beneath it

```
ParticleController {
    id: ctrl
    signal createEmitter(width, size, height, etc, etc)
}

Rectangle {
    id: mainArea
    ParticleSystem {
        id: sys1
        onCompleted: {
            ctrl.createEmitter.connect(sys1.createEmitter)
        }
        function createEmitter(size, width, height, rate, etc, etc) {
            sys1.createQmlObject(/* etc etc */)
        }
    }
}

Popup {
     contentItem: Rectangle {
         ParticleSystem {
            id: sys2
            onCompleted: {
                ctrl.createEmitter.connect(sys2.createEmitter)
            }
            function createEmitter(size, width, height, rate, etc, etc) {
               var obj = sys2.createQmlObject( /* etc etc */)
               obj.x = mapToItem(sys1, x, y).x
                /* etc etc */
            }
      }
  }

}
```

Comment: Obviously you neeed to specify width height etc but the basic idea is all there..

Comment: as mentioned, ParticleSystem as child of PopUp is not possible. Because the App has dozens of Dialogs/PopUps, and the Particles should be drawn also after PopUp was closed